# How to use date filter in ng2-smart-table in angular?

Tags: html, angular

I used ng2-smart-table module in my angular project, everything working fine, but i don't know how to filer a date column based on from and to date. any one have example  or link to correct solution please give. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is by using 'renderComponent' on your field. You can see an example here : https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/custom-edit-view/advanced-example-custom-editor.component.ts

Here is what I did it :

1. Create a new component, here SimpleDateComponent
2. Add it to your module declarations and entryComponents arrays
3. Use it from your 'setting', used by your ng2-smart-table

1) The new component

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-date',
    template: `{{value |date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}`,
})
export class SimpleDateComponent {
    @Input() value: Date;
}
```

2) The import

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {PrestationListComponent} from './prestation-list/prestation-list.component';
import {SimpleDateComponent} from './simple-date-component/simple-date-component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      PrestationListComponent, 
      SimpleDateComponent],
    entryComponents: [SimpleDateComponent]
})
export class PrestationsModule {
}
```

3) The settings object modified:

```
settings = {
        columns: {
            dueDate: {
                title: 'Deadline',
                type: 'custom',
                renderComponent: SimpleDateComponent
            }
        }
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be still open [[1]](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/711) on GitHub and a [potential PR](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/pull/802) is still in pending merge requests. PRECAUTION: For this specific solution, you need to explicitly modify few files in `ng2-smart-table` folder under `node_modules\` folder in your project and in case you happen to install the package again (`npm i ng2-smart-table`) then it'll override any changes you did in the `ng2-smart-table` folder. Take necessary measures like-- (generally `node_modules\` folder are part of your `.gitignore` file and not commited to the repo but you can hack it by) [explicitly commiting this folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534865/5644090) or take a backup of `ng2-smart-table` folder before performing any package update.
PS: Do remember `ng2-smart-table` is the only boilerplate to accomplish this task for e.g. there exists other [better options](https://www.ngdevelop.tech/best-angular-tables/) too